# android change image in listview when image clicked

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to make the image change in `ListView` when the image is clicked.(I'm using `ImageButton`)
I added a `ClickListener` in `Adapter` for changing image.
The result is nothing happened or changed when I drag up and down.
Is there any solution for refreshing?

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    mView = convertView;
    if(mView == null){
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mainview_item, null);
    }
    mItem = mArray.get(position);
    if(mItem != null){

        TextView mFileName, mLastestDate;
        mStatus  = (ImageButton)mView.findViewById(R.id.mainListViewItemImgBtn);
        mStatus.setBackground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selector));
        mStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mStatus.isSelected())
                    mStatus.setSelected(false);
                else
                    mStatus.setSelected(true);
            }
        });

        mFileName = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.mainListViewItemFn);
        mLastestDate = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.mainListViewItemLD);

        mFileName.setText("FileName");
        if(mItem.getmLastestDate() == null)
            mLastestDate.setText("2014-04-22 ㆍ 10.5 MB");
        else
            mLastestDate.setText("2014-04-22");
    }

    return mView;
}
```

**EDIT :**

I solved this problem using `ToggleButton` not `ImageButton` or `ImageView`.
Thanks for reply to all!

Comment: `mStatus.setSelected(false);`? It will only enable and disable button, you have to code for change image on click.

Comment: I'm using selector to change image and also mStatus.setBackground() not working.

Comment: You can fire a broadcast from imageView's click in your adapter and have a broadcastReceiver registered in the Activity that holds the list view. Then finally  in the onReceive method reset the adapter of your listView.

On imageView's click in your adapter you also need to update the data structure on which your list is based.